# In C, how am I able to use the printf() function to 'store' a string?

Tags: c, floating-point, bit, 16-bit

I am attempting to represent a `bit16` representation of a number (floating point representation) using `unsigned` integers. The fraction field here deviates from the standard of 10, and is 8 bits - implying the exponent field is 7 bits and the sign is 1 bit.

The code I have is as follows:

```
bit16 float_16(bit16 sign, bit16 exp, bit16 frac) {

 //make the sign the number before binary point, make the fraction binary.
 //concatenate the sign then exponent then fraction
 //

 bit16 result;
 int theExponent;

 theExponent = exp + 63; // bias = 2^(7-1) + 1 = 2^6 + 1 = 63

 //printf("%d",sign);
 int c, k;

 for(c = 6; c > 0; c--)
 {
     k = theExponent >> c;

     if( k & 1)
         printf("1");
     else
         printf("0");
 }

 for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
 {
     k = frac >> c;

     if( k & 1)
         printf("1");
     else
         printf("0");
 }



 //return result;
```

}

My thinking to 'recreate' a `16 bit` sequence from these fields is to concatenate them together as so, but if I want to use them in a further application I am unable to do so. Is there a way to store the final result after everything has been printed (`16-bit` sequence) into a variable which can then be represented as an unsigned integer? Or is there a more optimal way to do this procedure?

Comment: You can't store the result of printf. You can use `sprintf` but in this case it is probably simpler just to set individual characters in a char array.

Comment: @M.M, it's a typedef unsigned int.

Comment: Why not just use the C standard `uint16_t`?

Comment: @owacoder my assignment requires me that I implement it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

While `printf` will not work in this case (you can't 'store' it's result), you can use `sprintf`.

```
int sprintf ( char * output_str, const char * format, ... );
```

**`sprintf` writes formatted data to string**

Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on `printf`, but instead of being printed (or displayed on the console), the content is stored as a C string in the buffer pointed by `output_str`.

The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire resulting string. See [Buffer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

A terminating null character (`\0`) will automatically be appended at the end of your `output_str`.

**From `output_str` to an integer variable**

You can use the `atoi` function to do this. You can get your answer in an integer variable like this:

```
int i = atoi (output_str);
```

Comment: the binary wasn't displaying properly through this method. Any ideas for another strategy to do this?

Comment: What exactly happened? Was there some kind of error message?

Comment: in the code I provided, it would not print out the binary for the mantissa/fraction portion properly. I tried for hours and could not get it to work.